# mgt-person : Open user chat window

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I have implemented `mgt-person` in my Teams application and I have a problem when I click on the button to chat with a user.

The application is correctly open but a popup appears which informs me that the user doesn't exist even though I'm on the right account.

And I can't close this popup, so I'm completely stuck in the application.

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3 (I'm stuck here):

[image]

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue that was recently fixed in 1.2 of mgt. I recomend updating mgt and trying again.

In addition to this fix, we also have support for deep linking directly to chat without opening a new browser tab, [take a look at these docs for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/person-card#setup-for-teams-integrations)